# PHP PDO: Правильно ли я обрабатываю ошибки?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Пересматривал свой код и возник вопрос: А правильно ли я обрабатываю ошибки, которые могут возникнуть при подключении/сбое?

```
try
    {
        $res=$db->prepare($sql);
        $res->execute( [
                ":name"=>$name,
                ":surname"=>$surname
        ] );
    }catch(PDOException $err)
    {
        echo "Произошла ошибка на сервере";
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Делаем глобальный обработчик ошибок. Перехватываем и пишем в лог, при этом пользователю показываем красивую страницу о том, что временно сбой. Всё. А вот это вот - не нужно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский т.е использовать set_exception_handler()? Также хотелось бы уточнить что в официальной документации сказано что режим обработки ошибок PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION установлен по умолчанию начиная с PHP 8.0.0. Значит ли это что мне нужно принудительно установить этот режим, ну так, "на всякий случай" если например перенесу сайт на другой хостинг, а там будет PHP ниже 8-ой версии?

Comment: " т.е использовать set_exception_handler()?" --- да.  есть даже пример (не самый крутой, но вполне понятный)  https://www.phptutorial.net/php-oop/php-set-exception-handler/

Comment: "а там будет PHP ниже 8-ой версии? " --- лучше переносить туда, где будет точь-в-точь. Иначе могут быть проблемы. Например использование ?string приведёт к крэшу в 7.0 ....

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы! У меня остались ещё вопросы, точнее уточнение. 1) Я могу оставить пока так? Я имею ввиду мою реализацию можно назвать критичной ошибкой, требующей незамедлительного исправления? 2) Маленькое уточнение (что бы не создавать новый вопрос) по другой теме: В той же официальной документации говориться что закрывающий тег `?>` рекомендуется опустить, если кроме PHP-кода больше ничего нет. Но вот вопрос - если я подключаю файл (просто скрипт) к файлу в котором есть HTML, можно ли в подключаемом файле опустить закрывающий тег?

Comment: 1. - лучше сразу сделать правильно. Если это только для себя - можно. 2 - для шаблонов (lzk представлений view) - можно закрывать. Для контроллеров,сервисов,enitty, моделей и пр. где не может быть html в принципе - опускать тег ибо смысла нет

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз. Всего доброго!